# jquery mouseover-div placed at cursor doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, cursor, mouseover

I tried to program a mouseover in form of a div which opens when the mouse is over one line of a table. The div should open where the cursor is at the moment entering the line.
But my code doesn't work, maybe somebody can help me?
I searched for different types but no one is still working. Surely because of a stupid mistake because I taught myself programming.

```
<script>
    var mouseX;
    var mouseY;
    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
        mouseX = e.pageX; 
        mouseY = e.pageY;
    }); 
    $('.portfoliohover').mouseover(function() {
        $('#mask').css({
            'top': mouseY,
            'left': mouseX
        }).fadeIn('slow');
    });
    $('.portfoliohover').mouseout(function() {
        $('#mask').fadeOut('slow');
    });
</script>
```

```html
<tbody>
    <tr> 
        <!--Vorschaumouseover-->
        <td class="portfoliohover">
            <a href="portfoliodetail.html">Mosaiken Marc Chagall </a>
        </td>
```

```css
#mask {
    width: 190px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px; 
    border: 2px solid #cc0066;
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// maybe mousein ?    
$('.portfoliohover').mouseover(function() {
        $('#mask').css({
            'top': mouseY,
            'left': mouseX
        }).fadeIn('slow');
    });
```